# Parsing algorithm for nested XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

There are many parsing algorithms present how ever i am confused in which is better and efficient parser for deeply nested XML file?
Which is feasible parser algorithm for deeply nested XML file?

1. DOM
2. SAX
3. StAX
4. DOM4J
5. JAXB
6. JDOM
7. Other if any

Comment: Don't you think if there were a best algorithm, rest would have perished.

Comment: You should first stay with the standard Java parsers: DOM, SAX and StAX.  You can use DOM in conjunction with XPath for small XML documents. For DOM the whole document needs to be loaded into memory. For larger documents you should try StAX which is more modern than SAX and has a more pleasant API.

Comment: Give an example XML. Is it dynamic or fix, many or less tags, ...? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

DOM4J is best solution, i have used it.

Comment: Why is it the best? What have you used it for? With what are you comparing it?